# How to convert MySQL datetime to NSDate?

Tags: mysql, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

MySQL returns this datetime: *2014-05-07T16:58:44.000Z*

How, **with what datetime format** I can create **NSDate**?

I far as I found this, but it does not work:

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'Z'"];
NSDate *date = [df dateFromString: valueStr];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your format string is close, but you want to specify the milliseconds with `SSS`, too:

```
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX"];
```

Also, the `Z` in your date string stands for "Zulu" (i.e. GMT/UTC), so your `dateFormat` should use `Z` or `X` without quotes so that it correctly parses the string's time zone. Also, if you're building strings from dates, make sure to set your time zone accordingly. You also want to set your locale, too:

```
NSLocale *enUSPOSIXLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.locale = enUSPOSIXLocale;
formatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX";
formatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0];
```

See [Technical Q&A QA1480](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1480/_index.html) for more information.

---

You can also use the newer `NSISO8601DateFormatter`, which gets you out of some of those weeds:

```
NSISO8601DateFormatter *formatter = [[NSISO8601DateFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.formatOptions = NSISO8601DateFormatWithFullDate | NSISO8601DateFormatWithFullTime | NSISO8601DateFormatWithFractionalSeconds;
```